# Alternative to embedded Windows Media Player that can be embedded in Mono

Tags: macos, mono, windows-media-player

I have a Windows .NET C# Winforms application that I'm looking to port to OS-X (Lion) using Mono.

At the moment the application using an embedded Windows Media Player control to play some MP3s. I expose the play, pause, stop, volume and location bar (for jumping around the clips) controls on the form and also programmatically set the media URLs and control the clip location and volume. I also use the playstate and locationchanged events.

When trying to run my app on mono on OS-X I get the following error:
COM/ActiveX support is not implemented

I think this is probably expected and I need an alternative to Windows Media Player that I can embed on my form to play MP3s.

I've searched around and there seems to be a few options but nothing seems well covered/documented.

Does anyone know of an alternative to WMP that can be embedded in a form exposing some of the controls but also allowing programmatic control?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.